# C#: cannot convert string to string [] []

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding my code. The situation is the following: I am working with many arrays with data, all of same length. Then I want to build a second version with specific camps.

I have the following code:

```cs
string[][][] cuentasHFMPreFinal = new string[nroCuenta.Length][][];
string anoCubo = "'2019";
string escenarioCubo = "Control";
string versionCubo = "Version Vigente";
```

```cs
for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < nroCuenta.Length && j < nroCuenta.Length && k < nroCuenta.Length; i++, j++, k++){
cuentasHFMPreFinal[i] = anoCubo;
}
```

The idea would be to give specific values to the new array (which will have more dimensions, this is a brief example). End array would end as something like:

```
cuentasHFM [anoCubo][escenarioCubo][versionCubo][....][lastVar]
```

The error is on the *cuentasHFMPreFinal[i] = anoCubo* part, giving the error on title.

Full code is:

```cs
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
            //ARCHIVO CUENTAS AUTOMATICAS
            //obtener direccion de archivo
            string pathCuentasAuto = @"C:\DescargaHFM\data\cuentas_auto.txt";
            pathCuentasAuto = Path.GetFullPath(pathCuentasAuto);

            //leer lineas archivo y pasar a arreglo
            string[] cuentasAuto = File.ReadAllLines(pathCuentasAuto);

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
            //ARCHIVO HFM CHILE
            //obtener direccion de archivo
            string pathHFM = @"C:\DescargaHFM\data\HFM.txt";
            pathHFM = Path.GetFullPath(pathHFM);

            //leer lineas archivo y pasar a arreglo
            string[] hfm = File.ReadAllLines(pathHFM);

            //obtener separador tab
            string separadorTab = "\t";

            //separar lineas por separadores
            string[][] camposHFM = new string[hfm.Length][];
            for (int i = 0; i < hfm.Length; i++) {
                camposHFM[i] = hfm[i].Split(separadorTab.ToCharArray());
            }

            //arreglo con periodo(meses)
            string[] mesesHFM = new string[camposHFM.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < camposHFM.Length; i++)
            {
                string mesPeriodo = camposHFM[i][0];
                switch (mesPeriodo){
                    case "Per01":
                        mesPeriodo = "Jan";
                        break;
                    case "Per02":
                        mesPeriodo = "Feb";
                        break;
                    case "Per03":
                        mesPeriodo = "Mar";
                        break;
                    case "Per04":
                        mesPeriodo = "Apr";
                        break;
                    case "Per05":
                        mesPeriodo = "May";
                        break;
                    case "Per06":
                        mesPeriodo = "Jun";
                        break;
                    case "Per07":
                        mesPeriodo = "Jul";
                        break;
                    case "Per08":
                        mesPeriodo = "Aug";
                        break;
                    case "Per09":
                        mesPeriodo = "Sep";
                        break;
                    case "Per10":
                        mesPeriodo = "Oct";
                        break;
                    case "Per11":
                        mesPeriodo = "Nov";
                        break;
                    case "Per12":
                        mesPeriodo = "Dec";
                        break;
                }

                mesesHFM[i] = mesPeriodo;
            }


            //otener cantidad total y cantidad gl
            double[] QTotalUSGAP = new double[hfm.Length];
            double[] QTotalGL = new double[hfm.Length];
            double[] QTotalResta = new double[hfm.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < camposHFM.Length; i++) {
                QTotalUSGAP[i] = Double.Parse(camposHFM[i][3]);
                QTotalGL[i] = Double.Parse(camposHFM[i][4]);
                QTotalResta[i] = QTotalUSGAP[i] - QTotalGL[i];
            }

            //obtener numero cuenta
            string[] nroCuenta = new string[hfm.Length];

            /*Formula Excel:
             *SI(IZQUIERDA(C2;4)="ACCT";MED(C2;5;LARGO(C2)-3);IZQUIERDA(C2;ENCONTRAR("_";C2)-1))
            */
            for (int i = 0; i < camposHFM.Length; i++) {
                nroCuenta[i] = camposHFM[i][2];
                if (nroCuenta[i].Substring(0, 4) == "ACCT") {
                    nroCuenta[i] = nroCuenta[i].Substring(5, (nroCuenta[i].Length - 3));
                }
                else {
                    //int indexFind = nroCuenta[i].IndexOf('_');
                    //nroCuenta[i] = nroCuenta[i].Substring(0, (indexFind - 1));
                    nroCuenta[i] = nroCuenta[i].Substring(0, nroCuenta[i].Length);
                }
            }

            //comprobar existencia de nroCuenta en cuentasAuto
            string[] existeNroCuenta = new string[nroCuenta.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < nroCuenta.Length; i++){
                if (cuentasAuto.Contains(nroCuenta[i])){
                    existeNroCuenta[i] = "TRUE";
                }
                else{
                    existeNroCuenta[i] = "FALSE";
                }
            }

            //armar arreglo pre final
            string[][][] cuentasHFMPreFinal = new string[nroCuenta.Length][][];
            string anoCubo = "'2019";
            string escenarioCubo = "Control";
            string versionCubo = "Version Vigente";
            string monedaCubo = "CLP";
            string ubgCubo = "Generico UBG";
            string ajusteICCubo = "Ajuste 99";
            string organizacionCubo = "Generico";

            for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < nroCuenta.Length && j < nroCuenta.Length && k < nroCuenta.Length; i++, j++, k++){
                cuentasHFMPreFinal[i] = anoCubo;


            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you really need a 3-dimensional array? It really looks like you actually need to create a class to hold 3 pieces of data and then add them to a list.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? A brief description of the functionality should be better to help you out.

Comment: Didn't post full code, however, the final array would have some static camps (as seen in code), and others that come from other arrays that had data either extracted or validated elsewhere, for example, one that has account numbers, and another that has a validation if it exists or not. The end result would be an array which would have, if seen in an excel file, columns 1 to 3 of static value, column 4 with account numbers (which was extracted), column 5 a validator that confirms either it exists or not. Does this clarify it better?

Comment: I suggest that you learn about classes. Arrays should only be used for a list of similar data. Right now you are trying to store 3 strings that represent different things in a list.

Comment: If you're just representing columns and rows, you only need a two dimensional array (`string [,]`): one dimension represents columns and the other represents rows. But if you're representing actual objects (and their properties), a collection of some class that describes the data would likely be the better solution.

Comment: Added full code to try to show what I am trying to do, if it helps

Comment: On another note you can simplify a lot the month text loop. The whole code in your loop can be changed to 1 line with `mesesHFM[i] = new DateTime(2000, Convert.ToInt32(camposHFM[i][0].Substring(3)), 1).ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Addendum:
I got helped from on-site IT guy, and I was tangling myself in some problems. What I just needed to do was ```string[,] cuentasHFMPreFinal = new string[nroCuenta.Length,10];``` and then change the (10) and pute the value I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Use classes, structs or tuples to achieve what you're trying to achieve.